# Lightning CLI for Static resource

Tags: lightning, lightning-cli

I was using Moment.js in my static resource. But after Winter 17 update it stopped working. So i have to make some changes in moment.js to make it work.
Now my Question is How can we run lightning cli check for static resource.
If i have only static resource in my folder then lightning cli will not run.

Then what i tried is copied a .cmp file in same folder in which moment.js is present. then when i ran Lightning cli scan i got Following Error

> /home/manjot/.local/share/heroku/plugins/node_modules/salesforce-lightning-cli/rules/ecma-intrinsics.js:64
>                       if (!api.hasOwnProperty(token)) {
>                                ^
>
> TypeError: api.hasOwnProperty is not a function
>       at EventEmitter.MemberExpression (/home/manjot/.local/share/heroku/plugins/node_modules/salesforce-lightning-cli/rules/ecma-intrinsics.js:64:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at NodeEventGenerator.enterNode (/home/manjot/.local/share/heroku/plugins/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:40:22)
>       at CodePathAnalyzer.enterNode (/home/manjot/.local/share/heroku/plugins/node_modules/eslint/lib/code-path-analysis/code-path-analyzer.js:607:23)
>       at CommentEventGenerator.enterNode (/home/manjot/.local/share/heroku/plugins/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/comment-event-generator.js:97:23)
>       at Controller.traverser.traverse.enter (/home/manjot/.local/share/heroku/plugins/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint.js:905:36)
>       at Controller.__execute (/home/manjot/.local/share/heroku/plugins/node_modules/estraverse/estraverse.js:397:31)
>       at Controller.traverse (/home/manjot/.local/share/heroku/plugins/node_modules/estraverse/estraverse.js:501:28)
>       at Controller.Traverser.controller.traverse (/home/manjot/.local/share/heroku/plugins/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/traverser.js:36:33)

I need to know how we can check static resource file using lighnting cli?

Answer (score 0):

If you sync your static resource in your ide (mavensmate/eclipse), it'll download the resource to your local machine. Then you run the ClI with the --files option.

```
heroku lightning:lint ./path/to/static/resource --files **/*fileName.js
```

Comment: i have done that but lightning cli is not able to recognize any js file in static resource folder.